# EXCEL - Get content of specific cell using by combining number/letter in 2 cells to get location of content

Tags: excel, excel-formula, location, cell

This is probably basic but I just cant find solution.
What I need to do is:
I have a value in cell A2 and I have a numeric value in cell C1 witch is 2 and I want to create a formula that works a bit like this **=A +C1** and the output is the value inside A2.
And if I change value in C1 to 5 it outputs value inside A5 (=A+C1).
Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is the `INDIRECT()` function, e.g.: `=INDIRECT("A"&C1)`. However, keep in mind this is volatile! I'd rather go with `INDEX()`, e.g.: `=INDEX(A:A,C1)`

Comment: WOW. Fast answer. Index worked perfectly. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to increment cell number.

You can use Address and Indirect functions to get the value which is there in that address

Address "=ADDRESS(C1,1)"   A2
Indirect  "=INDIRECT(A2)".     Gives the value

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C1,1))